# chart js update X-axis value based on user selection from drop-down in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

token.html

```
 <mat-form-field>
            <mat-select formControlName="selectedValue" >
                <mat-option (click)="TokenPrice()" *ngFor="let c of value" [value]="c.viewValue">{{c.value}}</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
```

token.ts

```
 value:coins[] = [
    {value:'USDT', viewValue:'0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7'},
    {value:'BUSD', viewValue:'0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7'},
    {value:'SHIB', viewValue:'0x95aD61b0a150d79219dCF64E1E6Cc01f0B64C4cE'},
    {value:'WBTC', viewValue:'0x2260FAC5E5542a773Aa44fBCfeDf7C193bc2C599'},
  ]
```

getting selected value as

```
  get selectedValue():FormControl{
    return this.loginForm.get("selectedValue") as FormControl
  }
```

for every drop-down selection, returns token price.Token Price keeps changing based on selection.

```
  async TokenPrice(){
    this.TokenUsdPrice = await Promise.all( await this.blocks.map(async (e,i)=>
    await Moralis.Web3API.token.getTokenPrice({address:this.selectedValue.value,to_block:e.block})
  ))  
    this.filtereTokenPrice();
  }
```

I want to display TokenPrice(Dynamic) in X-axis and Dates(constant) in Y-axis.

```
  async filtereTokenPrice(){
    this.usd = await this.TokenUsdPrice.map(item=>item.usdPrice);//get usdprice
    this.chart = new Chart('canvas',{
      type:'line',
     data:{
      labels:this.service.getdates(),
      datasets:[
        {
          data:this.usd,
          borderWidth:1,
          fill:false
        }
      ]
     }
    })
    
  }
```

this works only for 1 selection and displays as needed. When I select other options I get

```
 Error: Canvas is already in use. Chart with ID '0' must be destroyed before the canvas can be reused.
Error: Canvas is already in use. Chart with ID '0' must be destroyed before the canvas can be reused.
```

How do I update X-axis values for every other selction.If more information or stackslibz needed please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.destroy()`

> Use this to destroy any chart instances that are created. This will clean up any references stored to the chart object within Chart.js, along with any associated event listeners attached by Chart.js. This must be called before the canvas is reused for a new chart.

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html#destroy

```js
  async filtereTokenPrice(){
    this.usd = await this.TokenUsdPrice.map(item=>item.usdPrice);//get usdprice
     this.chart.destroy(); // <----- 
      this.chart = new Chart('canvas',{
      type:'line',
     data:{
      labels:this.service.getdates(),
      datasets:[
        {
          data:this.usd,
          borderWidth:1,
          fill:false
        }
      ]
     }
    })
    
  }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

```js
@ViewChild('canvas') chart;
```

Comment: I did try this, But I keep getting typeError: _this5.chart.destroy is not a function, even if there is no type error. In my code, I have typed as clearly as possible. I don't understand why there this error

Comment: I have used this.chart.destroy(). as simple as that.

Comment: stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/github/HemanthGirimath/Crypto-Dashboard?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhero-section%2Ftokens%2Ftokens.component.ts

Comment: Oh. I have edited my answer. `chart` can't simply be an `[]` you must query the canvas element by id. `@ViewChild('chart') chart;` viewChild is possible in `AfterViewInit()` cycle earliest, and in html you just do `<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>`. Follow the example and refactor your code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-area-chart-ssguhd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: can You please do the changes in the stackblitz?. I tried but I'm not working . Thank you

Comment: @viewChild in ngAfterViewInit() is not working .

Comment: `@ViewChild` is adectorator on variable that should be declared outside of a method. `ngAfterViewInit()` is a lifecycle where you can access that variable the earliest. https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild#example-2

Comment: I'm sorry about asking so many questions, but what should I do inside AfterViewInit()? I'm a bit confused. I did query the id canvas as you said and did call the .destroy() method.

Comment: typeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'destroy'). STILL THIS ERROR so...I'm lost honestly,

Comment: so If I use the whole chart config inside AfterViewInit() then It won't be dynamic, because I'm using click listener to trigger filterTokenPrice inside which I had called the chart config

Comment: Simplest would be to reproduce the problem online e.g Stackblitz where we can help you more easily.

Comment: I did already- https://stackblitz.com/github/HemanthGirimath/Crypto-Dashboard?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhero-section%2Ftokens%2Ftokens.component.ts

Comment: And have you checked that it works too? Right now you have some dependency issues in there.

Comment: Can you just update the charts part in the tokens.ts file. Stackblitz for this project in not working. I tried a lot it keeps saying cant find src package. I did change all import paths to relative and still its not working on stacklibtz. so please just update the required things. Would be very help full

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-area-chart-srr548?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts I don't know how you want to consume your data. But here is a working chart of what I talked about.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246058/discussion-between-hemanth-girimath-and-joosep-parts).